# Write CSV table for join self in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-joins, table, relates

I wonder how I would write a table for a join which I want to perform.
Right now I wrote a `.txt` File, tab-seperated. The headerline only contains letters.
Here is the problematic table: http://www.filedropper.com/lookuptable
I am working with the shapes provided here: http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/clc-2006-vector-data-version

Thats how my file looks like:

```
ID  CLCCode CLCKlasse
1   111 test1
2   112 test2
3   121 test3
4   122 test4
5   123 test5
6   124 test6
...
```

Rightclick on the `.shp`. I choose my `.txt` file and the two needed fields to perform the join (my key and value pair). My key would be numbers in the attribute table of the shapefile which equals the numbers I wrote in my `.txt` file.
But, ArcGIS says that there are no matching records.

I also tried it with a `,` as a seperator. I can choose in the dialog `join` the textfile, but, the field where it should be stays empty/blanc (it basically gets not selected).

Also, there is something I do not understand. When I open my `.csv` file in ArcGIS I see the "CLCCODE" column.But, I cannot choose "CLCCODE" in the Join Dialog, although it is a column of the attribute table.

[image: Screen]

Comment: An ASCII file isn't a table, just a potential source for a table.  Please **edit** the question to specify details of the manifestation of unhappiness.

Comment: @Vince updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ArcGIS 10.1 Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000010000000):

> Files with a .txt, .asc, or .csv extension are interpreted as comma
>   delimited, while files with a .tab extension are interpreted as tab
>   delimited by default. Any file with one of these extensions will be
>   interpreted as a text file table even if it doesn't contain tabular
>   data. If you attempt to display a text file that doesn't contain
>   tabular data, the software will either produce an error or attempt to
>   display the data as a table. To avoid this problem, give your
>   delimited text files a .csv or a .tab extension. This will help
>   differentiate text files with delimited data from unformatted text
>   files.

Try changing the extension to .tab and see if that works.

Edit:

The problem with your join is the field in the shapefile is a Text field. Make a new integer field and use the field calculator to copy over the values. The join worked for me after I did that.

Comment: nope. that did not help.

Comment: Can you verify that your file is actually tab delimited? The sample you posted in your question only has one space between CLCCode and CLCKlasse.

Comment: Yes I can! There are only tabs!

Comment: You may need to provide a sample text file to see whether others can reproduce your result.

Comment: I will in a sec. What is weird though is that when i save it as a `.tab` file I only get to chose as "value to join" to in the "join Dialog" the `CLCKlasse`.

Comment: provided the .csv file

Comment: The page you linked to in your question provides raster data (.tif), not a .shp file. If it is the case you are working with a .tif, you will need to build the raster attribute table using this tool: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000m2000000. The join worked for me after building an attribute table.

Comment: Shoot. Linked the wrong site. There is a vector data which contains similar information. However, the vector layer I am working with is processed thus differs from the ones provided here: http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/clc-2006-vector-data-version

Comment: Edited my answer above to what I believe will fix it.

Comment: @Stophface Join must be based on fields of the same data type. If it's a string in your shapefile, it needs to be a string in your table. By default Arc scans the first 8 lines to determine data type. As suggested in some of your previous questions, when bringing in a text file to ArcGIS you can create a schema.ini file that defines the datatype for each of the columns to what you want rather than letting ArcGIS pick. This is discussed towards the bottom of the help file that juturna links to in the answer.

Comment: @ChrisW thanks for the hint. The problem this time was not on the side of the thextfile but of the shapefile. I did not expect the field from the shapefile on which I base my join to be formatted to text since its numbers in there which are the keys to a greater table...

Comment: @Stophface It may be stored as text for a reason. Just because characters are numeric doesn't mean they are a number per se. For example US Zip codes are five numeric characters but aren't really numbers (there's no productive math you could perform on them), so they're usually stored as strings (or should be if following convention). One primary reason for this might be leading zeros, which can't be stored in a numeric. In your case here, I wouldn't say there was a *problem* with either file, unless the greater table your refer to has them stored a particular way or they're supposed to be.